# How do I handle very large data (100000 javascript objects) in webpack-react-node based website?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, reactjs, mongodb

I have a react-node based website in which I need to work on a dataset close to 100000 javascript objects, all objects containing the same set of keys. Various functionalities have to be implemented like display suggestions on searching by name, sorting, filtering, all of which need to be as fast as instantaneous.

There are a few options which I thought of:

```
1.) Storing all the data in a relational database (SQL) with keys as the column name.

v/s

2.) Storing all the data in a non-relational database (MongoDB) as an array of objects.

v/s

3.) Storing all the data in a .js file in the server as `export const data={Array-Of_Objects}`
```

In the functionality in which when input is typed in a search box, suggestions are shown, I think that I can't keep going back to the database to fetch all the objects and then perform processing to find best suggestions as soon as a letter is typed to maintain fast functionality.

Hence, I decided to follow the third option but still, the .js file containing all the data is close to 100 MB and importing the data using `const {data}= require(./file.js)` is not happening, let alone processing and finding the best suggestions, which happens when I reduce the data size from 100000 objects to (say) 5000 objects.

If I divide all the data into various .js files and import them separately, I think still the importing of all the files and the processing of data will not be fast enough.

Please suggest me what is the best method to follow or free technology to use.

Comment: You can use ```pagination``` and ```lazy load```. You can divide the data to multiple files and only load the file when you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are working now. I am accessing the data from the backend from the database as soon as the user presses first 2-3 character. The result thus obtained is of lower size than the complete database. And then from the next request onward I am filtering the last results in javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way according to me would be have them stored in DB(MongoDB or RDBMS) and implement lazy loading don't import data in React component it will cause performance issue because Dom Tree will be heavy in that case and if any changes in data will take time to compare which node is changed.

Still if you don't want to use any DB i'll suggest use [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) here you can store the data in a single file and then make rest call to get the data and do the manipulation in redux, here as well you can go with lazy loading.

You are just storing data somewhere(DB,js file) how you are going to access data and display in component performance matters there if you have 100000 javascript object am sure you are not going to display all of them at a time so better filter it in redux and only pass the data which will be usefull to component.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have problem using database or json-server as long as it works. I just want to clear some things. I am implementing search function with suggestions in the dropdown, in which the keyword typed into the search input is compared with the 'name' key of all the objects (even before submitting) and dropdown shows the responses, as you can see while searching a course in Coursera. Will the passing of keyword to the redux, fetching the data and comparing the keyword with the 'name' key of all the objects, returning the response happen instantaneously with each letter I type?

Comment: I have implemented similar functionality in one of my projects i'll give you idea  so one option is call API and get filter result from DB itself and display in UI, if your API is taking long time to return result what you can do is as soon as user presses first 2/3 character call API get result suppose you have 100000  records so as soon as user presses 2/3 characters your list will be smaller than actual size and from next request onward filter in java-script side itself.

Comment: Thank you technipank, this totally helped. I am getting data from the API when 2-3 characters are typed and then filtering on the front-end when more characters are typed.

Comment: If answer helped, please accecpt my answer and close this ticket, Happy Coding :)